# Switching to VIM window by name

Tags: windows, vim

There are some excellent Vim plugins for switching to a specific [file](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025) or [buffer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890&gt) by typing part of the name. Does anyone know of a plugin like these that allows for quickly switching between open windows?

For example, if I had a vsplit with a file named 'a.txt' on one side and 'b.txt' on another I'd like to be able to switch between them by typing the filename (or just 'a' or 'b' with incremental searching). This might not be too useful for two windows, but I often have up to 5 windows open, so switching between them using the normal navigation buttons can be a pain.

WinWalker seems to support this type of functionality, but wrapped inside of a much larger framework for window navigation.

Comment: Do you really look at all the windows at the same time? Using the built in `:b part-of-file-name` can get you far, I prefer using that one (actually I use tabs mostly) than having too many windows. Sometimes it's the programs that should adjust to us, sometimes it's us to them :)

Comment: (And no, I don't know the answer to your question, just trying to zoom out a bit)

Comment: Well, often I have two files open at the same time, and those are usually split into two so I can reference parts of the file while working on another. And then I have another window with my tags shown, and then finally a file tree.

Comment: Just to add, I have this in my vimrc: `noremap <silent> ,h :wincmd h<CR>` plus the 3 subsequents

Answer (score 6):

`:b` does that happily if you have `:set`[`switchbuf`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27switchbuf%27)`+=useopen`
(in your vimrc). It supports file name [completion](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#cmdline-completion), e.g. with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>.

<sub>by *MarcWeber* et al from [#vim](http://vi-improved.org/)</sub>

Comment: Doesn't work with `:b`, but does work with `:sbuffer`, as in `:sbuffer NAME`. Here `NAME` is the name of the buffer to jump to. Works with a partial match on `NAME` as well.

Answer (score 4):

@Aaron Thoma' s answer with `switchbuf+=useopen` did not work for me. Actually the doc does not mention that the setting is supported by `:b` comand.

I've used the following snippet:

```
let windowNr = bufwinnr(pattern)
if windowNr > 0
  execute windowNr 'wincmd w'
endif
```

[See bufwinnr()](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#bufwinnr())

Comment: Just to add that this is not replacing the current buffer, but instead goes to the relevant open window, which is exactly what was specified in the question

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small function I came up with after trying to achieve the same thing

```
function! ActivateWindowByName(name)
    let l:bufid = bufnr(a:name)
    let l:winids = win_findbuf(l:bufid)
    call win_gotoid(l:winids[0])
endfunction
```

Explanation:

- `bufnr('substring-of-buffer-name')` returns the buffer number
- `win_findbuf(buffer_number)` returns a list of window IDs (not the same thing as buffer number) that use the buffer identified with `buffer_number`
- `win_gotoid(window_ID)` goes to the window identified with `window_ID` that can be in a different tabpage from the current one

`bufnr` isn't guaranteed to find a buffer, so it can return `-1`. In that case, `win_findbuf` will find an empty list and `[0]` will be out of range.

Comment: I'm using VIM 7.4 and I don't have win_findbuf and win_gotoid

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to switch to a window based on the filename, but I use the following shortcuts in my `.vimrc` to move between windows.

```
noremap <S-W> <C-w><Up>
noremap <S-S> <C-w><Down>
noremap <S-A> <C-w><Left>
noremap <S-D> <C-w><Right>
```

These are just as simple, and I don't have more than 4 windows open, so I'm never more than 2 window movements away from any window. Also, you *don't* have to type the filename.

I use the standard FPS movement keys, `wasd` to move between windows as it's intuitive to me, and I don't have to shift my fingers to the arrow keys -- pinky on the shift and the other three on the letters. You can change them to whatever you're comfortable with (`hjkl` would be a good alternate)

I prefer to use `Shift` instead of `Ctrl/Alt/Option/Cmd` because the locations and sizes vary between keyboards (e.g., `Fn` is the leftmost on a macbook pro, whereas `Ctrl` is the leftmost on a full mac keyboard) and I've had issues with vim on Linux not recognizing the `Cmd` key.

Comment: You don't need to use `<S-` because `W`, `S`, `A`, `D` should work just fine. And use `nnoremap`: 1) you don't need this behavior in operator-pending mode and probably don't need it in visual and select modes too; 2) you don't know that op has not remapped `<C-w>` to something other then window handling.

Comment: That's right. The way it stands now, you don't need the `<S-`. It's just the weird ways in which my `.vimrc` evolves. I don't even remember when those became capitalized. As for point 2, `<C-w>` is the default for window movements. If the OP has remapped it, then he/she should adjust accordingly.

Comment: M. But if you add `nore` before `map`, then you will get your solution working regardless whether OP has or has not remapped it. And it is bad to suggest adjusting instead: with this approach you may end in having maps that depend on each other and thus removing or changing one of these maps will lead to the debugging hell.

Comment: @yoda: Since you agree with ZyX, why didn't you edit your answer to reflect that? I hope you don't mind I took the liberty of doing it.

Comment: @accolade Thanks. I was new then and was not aware of the conventions :) I've approved your edit.

Answer (score 0):

This uses the python api, so you'll only be able to use it in vim, but I'm sure someone who loves vim script could convert it easily enough.

Use it like this:

```
:WSeek win
:WSeek READ
:WSeek README
:WSeek a.
etc.
```

No auto completion I'm afraid. Sorry~

```
" Call using:
" :source window-swap.vim or put in plugins dir

function! WSeek(target) 
  if !has('python')
    echo "Error: this plugin requires vim with +python"
    finish
  else
python << EOF

import vim

target = vim.eval("a:target")
found = False
for i in range(0, len(vim.windows)):
  vim.command(str(i+1) + "wincmd w")
  bits = vim.current.buffer.name.split("/")
  bits = bits[-1]
  if (bits.startswith(target)):
    found = True
    break

# Go back to the start on no match
if not found:
  vim.command("1wincmd w")

EOF
  endif
endfunction 

command! -nargs=1 WSeek :call WSeek(<q-args>)
```

Comment: Strange command: `vim.command("exe 1 . \"wincmd w\"")`. No need to do eval inside eval here: just `vim.command("1wincmd w")`.

Comment: Same for above: `vim.command(str(i+1)."wincmd w")`. What you actually did is equivalent to `execute "execute ".(i+1).".\"wincmd w\""`. Looks weird, does not it?

Comment: ^_^! oh yeah, good point. Solution edited to reflect @ZyX 's awesomeness. :)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using the [Command-T](https://wincent.com/products/command-t) plugin. It indexes the files in the current folder (and its subfolders) and allows you to type part of a file name to open it. In my .vimrc, I also added this link:

```
nnoremap <S-F12> :CommandT<CR>
```

this way I press Shift-F12 and type the file name to open it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I linked to CommandT in the original post. It's definitely very helpful (and part of what made me want this functionality) but that is for loading files in a specific buffer, not for changing to another existing window.

Comment: Yes, right, but than what is the difference for you? I used to think the same at the beginning, but then when I asked myself, what is the difference between opening the buffer through a buffer list and opening the buffer through a file list that will open switch the buffer since it is already opened? Don't be perfectionist man :-)